# Remove redundant rows and update foreign references

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SQL`-Table called `tblEmployees` like:

```
sid primaryId   secondaryId employeeId  employeeName       timestamp
1   123         40          1           Eastwood, Clint    20141016124013
2   123         40          1           Eastwood, Clint    20141016130043
3   123         40          1           Westwood, Clint    20141016165733
4   123         40          1           Westwood, Clint    20141016210205
```

And I have a table called `tblEmployeeData` with a column `employeeIdentificataion` which references to the column `sid` of `tblEmployees`.

The table `tblEmployeeData` looks like

```
sid   employeeIdentificataion    data
86    4                       [binary data]
89    2                       [binary data]     
90    1                       [binary data] 
104   3                       [binary data]
```

Now I need to remove the redundant rows in `tblEmployees` and update the references in `tblEmployeeData` with the youngest entry in `tblEmployees`. To identify the youngest I can use the timestamp. To identify duplicates I have to use the columns `primaryId`, `secondaryId`, `employeeId` and `employeeName`.

Background of this problem is that in our application every time employee-data is added a new record will be added to tblEmployees. We need to know if the employeeName changes. Unfortunately we're not able to check the changing name before inserting the new record.

I would be able to do this in c# with an SQL-Connection. Unfortunately I have to do this in sql because of the performance-aspect.

Can anybody give me a hint or some help how to start over with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something which can do your task :

```
;WITH cte_todelete
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId, employeeName
                    ORDER BY sid) AS rn
         FROM   tblEmployees)
DELETE FROM cte_todelete
WHERE  rn > 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` will assign incremental number (starting from 1) to each group of `primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId, employeeName` with ascending order of `sid`. and `delete from CTE` will delete the rows except first one of the group.

note : replace `ORDER BY sid` with your desired criteria that which row should remain in table like `order by timestamp desc` or `order by timestamp`

EDIT :
Run this script at once to change the references and delete redundant records :

```
IF( Object_id('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL )
    DROP TABLE #temptable;

SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (
           partition BY primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId, employeeName
           ORDER BY timstamp DESC) AS rn
INTO   #temptable
FROM   tblEmployees

UPDATE r
SET    r.employeeIdentificataion = t2.sid
FROM   tblEmployeeData r
       JOIN #temptable t1
         ON r.employeeIdentificataion = t1.sid
       JOIN #temptable t2
         ON t1.primaryId = t2.primaryId
            AND t1.secondaryId = t2.secondaryId
            AND t1.employeeId = t2.employeeId
            AND t1.employeeName = t2.employeeName
            AND t1.sid <> t2.sid
            AND t2.rn = 1

DELETE m
FROM   tblEmployees m
       JOIN #temptable t
         ON m.sid = t.sid
WHERE  t.rn > 1;
```

Check this in sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6d0b/2).

Comment: Ok. And if I want to just keep the newest (column `timestamp`) I have to order it by that column right?

Comment: It just works fine. Now I have the problem, that I have foreign-key references to the rows which I want to remove. Can I change these references also within this statement?

Comment: Ok. This works. But I don't want to delete the references. I just want to change them to the remaining entry in the table.

Comment: remaining means , you want to update their `sid` with some other?

Comment: Exactly. I want to remove the duplicate entries and change the references to these duplicates to the one entry which is not a duplicate

Comment: Your last update is really close to that I need. But I don't know the target sid. that should be the original of the duplicates



and is `DELETE m 
 FROM maintable m 
 JOIN #temptable m 
 ON r.sid = t.sid ` correct?

Comment: yes, updated that delete statement. your last comment stuck in my head :) well, I am trying my best and will update the answer if I find some way. Till then you should update the question with the information you gave me in comments because that is important for others who want to answer this post.

Comment: updated answer as well as sql fiddle with your table names and column names.

Comment: It works. I just had another table which references to the duplicated entries :). Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The below query will keep the latest records for  primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId,employeeName combination

```
with mycte as
(
select primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId,employeeName,min(timestamp) as mntmstp
from tbl
group by primaryId, secondaryId, employeeId,employeeName
)delete from mycte
```

Comment: it will show error because you have used `aggregate/group` by in your query. Here is the message `Cannot update the view or function 'mycte' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.`

Comment: yes, I tested this query in my sql server and attached same error in my previous comments.